# How do I sort the buttons generated from the following code alphabetically base on string values

Tags: android, list, sorting, button, alphabetical

```
<string name="Manuf0">best</string>
<string name="Manuf1">Bravo</string>
<string name="Manuf2">zoo</string>
<string name="Manuf3">Skitz</string>
<string name="Manuf4">don</string>
<string name="Manuf5">animal</string>

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    scrollviewManuf = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout linearlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    scrollviewManuf.addView(linearlayout);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

    {

        LinearLayout linearManuf = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearManuf.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearlayout.addView(linearManuf);

        Manufb = new Button(this);

        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("Manuf" + i, "string", getPackageName());
        String Manuf = getResources().getString(id);
        Manufb.setText(Manuf);
        Manufb.setId(i);
        Manufb.setTextSize(30);
        Manufb.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

        // b.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF,Typeface.ITALIC);

        Manufb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        linearManuf.addView(Manufb);


        Manufb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String SManuf= Manuf.replaceAll("&","").replaceAll(" ","").replaceAll("/","").replaceAll(" / ","").replaceAll("/ ","").replaceAll(" /","".replaceAll("&amp;",""));
               //Panel= getResources().getString(id);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), SManuf , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent passIntent = new Intent(Manufacturers.this,panels.class);
                passIntent.putExtra("SManuf",SManuf);
                startActivity(passIntent);
            }

        });

    }

    this.setContentView(scrollviewManuf);
}
}
```

How do I sort the buttons generated from the following code alphabetically base on string values.
Currently they are listed as the buttons are produced 0 through to 5.

The list is in an xml string file, want to eb alphabetical so I can just add more to the file as needs be, and the programming just sort it alphabetically which suits me.

Not been able to find anything  yet , but I am gueesing I may need to define the list in the file and sort that list can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Okay, so I can see the code is doing something but the sort order isn't changing and the String s is showing up in intellij as not used, :  new code below:-

marked the sections  with // here

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayList<String> theStrings = new ArrayList<>();//Here
    scrollviewManuf = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout linearlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    scrollviewManuf.addView(linearlayout);

    for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {

        LinearLayout linearManuf = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearManuf.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearlayout.addView(linearManuf);

        Manufb = new Button(this);

        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("Manuf" + i, "string", getPackageName());
        String Manuf = getResources().getString(id);
        theStrings.add(Manuf); /// Here
        Manufb.setText(Manuf);
        Manufb.setId(i);
        Manufb.setTextSize(30);
        Manufb.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

        // b.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF,Typeface.ITALIC);

        Manufb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        linearManuf.addView(Manufb);


        Manufb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                String PManuf =Manuf;
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String SManuf= Manuf.replaceAll("&","").replaceAll(" ","").replaceAll("/","").replaceAll(" / ","").replaceAll("/ ","").replaceAll(" /","".replaceAll("&amp;",""));
               //Panel= getResources().getString(id);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Manuf+" Selected" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent passIntent = new Intent(Manufacturers.this,panels.class);
                passIntent.putExtra("SManuf",SManuf);
                passIntent.putExtra("PManuf",PManuf);
                startActivity(passIntent);
            }

        } );

    } Collections.sort(theStrings);   //here
    for (String s : theStrings) {  //here
        //...

    this.setContentView(scrollviewManuf); }//here
}
```

}

The following code is looping each time it loops its adding an extra repeated option.

ie. Cat,dog,mouse, donkey correct list  is the list but I am getting, Cat, dog.dog, mouse,mouse,mouse, donkey, donkey, donkey,donkey but still no sorting, still working on it but here is the code.

```
ArrayList<String> theStrings = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier("Manuf" + i, "string", getPackageName());
            String Manuf = getResources().getString(id);
            theStrings.add(Manuf);
            Collections.sort(theStrings);
        for (String s : theStrings) {


            LinearLayout linearManuf = new LinearLayout(this);
            linearManuf.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            linearlayout.addView(linearManuf);

            Manufb = new Button(this);
            Manufb.setText(Manuf);
            Manufb.setId(i);
            Manufb.setTextSize(30);
            Manufb.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

            // b.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF,Typeface.ITALIC);

            Manufb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            linearManuf.addView(Manufb);

            Manufb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String PManuf = Manuf;
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String SManuf = Manuf.replaceAll("&", "").replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("/", "").replaceAll(" / ", "").replaceAll("/ ", "").replaceAll(" /", "".replaceAll("&amp;", ""));
                    //Panel= getResources().getString(id);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Manuf + " Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent passIntent = new Intent(Manufacturers.this, panels.class);
                    passIntent.putExtra("SManuf", SManuf);
                    passIntent.putExtra("PManuf", PManuf);
                    startActivity(passIntent);
                }

            });

        }
    }
    this.setContentView(scrollviewManuf);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read it into a list, sort it and loop over it:

```
ArrayList<String> theStrings = new ArrayList<>();
 for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("Manuf" + i, "string", getPackageName());
    String Manuf = getResources().getString(id);
    theStrings.add(Manuf);
}
Collections.sort(theStrings);

for (String s : theStrings) {

    LinearLayout linearManuf = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearManuf.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearlayout.addView(linearManuf);

    Manufb = new Button(this);

    Manufb.setText(s);  // <-- use the String here
    Manufb.setId(i);
    Manufb.setTextSize(30);
    Manufb.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    // b.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF,Typeface.ITALIC);

    Manufb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    linearManuf.addView(Manufb);
```

...

Comment: Thanks,  not sure I am integrating this corectly no errors but no sorting either. I will play on  for a bit.

Comment: add some code?  not following  this and not sure what I am doing. I can see that we are putting a list theStrings together from the list generated for the buttons but I don't see how the list the Strings is taken from the strings take, other than  thestrings.add(Manuf);  so I am missing some code? or I just need to work out what goes where excactly?

Comment: show some code, saying it doesn't work usually isn't enough, unless you post the code you're using, there's no way to tell what's wrong

Comment: I will have another play and post the code I have entered/ how the section looks modified

Comment: cant add its too long to add here,  by 1700+ characters

Comment: worked it out doh must seem stupid at times thanks for helping its appreciated

Comment: worked it out doh must seem stupid at times thanks for helping its appreciated on posting the code that is not the solution to the sorting the list.

Comment: You need to sort it first before you create the Layouts. I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: okay still struggling updated my code on here, I am obviously missing something very simple I either get nothing crashes out, get the list but not sorted and my latest code gets duplication increasing as it goes down the list but still doesn't sort it, some of the values have / or & separating them if that is likey to inhibit the process of sorting. ie Cat & Mouse, Cat/ Mouse, Dog/Cat/Mouse

Comment: still no go,  will revisit later for now I will crack on with the rest of it, worst case I manually sort that one section